# How to upload git enterprise qcow file in proxmox

Tags: github, github-enterprise, proxmox

I have Proxmox VE, and I want to install Git enterprises in it via the qcow2 file I have downloaded the qcow2 of git enterprise, in my local but I don't know how to upload it in the Proxmox, because there is no option in proxmox to upload other than uploading an ISO image.

How should I upload a qcow2 file from my local system to Proxmox?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to `scp` the `.qcow2` file to your root user. After that you have to import it, and `<storagepool>` is per your set up, then rescan your storage. So something like the following:

```bash
scp git.qcow2 root@proxmox1:/root/
ssh root@proxmox1
qm importdisk 9000 git.qcow2 <storagepool>
qm rescan
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, but is there any option to upload the qcow2 file same as the iso image ??

Comment: Not that i know of, the qcow2 is a "hard drive" while an iso is like a "cd-rom." They leverage completely different mechanisms, and would require that feature to be created.